# Search for multiple paths in a tar archive

Tags: regex, shell, grep, tar

I know I can search for multiple `strings` like below in a `tar`

```
tar -tf $file |  egrep -i 'str1|str2|str3'
```

that gives me many paths I am not interested like e.g. the string str1 is *bfoa*

```
/data/misc/user/0/info.bfoa.com
/data/app/info.bfoa.com
/data/data/info.bfoa.com
```

and if str2 is `ubercab`

```
/data/misc/user/0/com.ubercab
    /data/app/com.ubercab
    /data/data/com.ubercab
```

are matches from `tar` listing. From these I only need ones that are
`/data/data/*string*` pattern like e.g.
/data/data/com.ubercab

I tried

```
 tar -tf $file |  egrep -i '/data/data/*str1*|/data/data/*str2*|/data/data/*str3*'
```

It says

```
egrep: repetition-operator operand invalid
```

so how do I get these things in a `tar` search in just that 1 `grep` attempt:
-List of searches search1|search2|search3
-Searches should be `regexes`
-search string should search through paths for a match 
-want just the parent directory `/data/data/com.ubercab` & not its content displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the regex pattern you want for egrep is:

```
tar tf bundle.tar | egrep -E "/data/data/.*(str1|str2|str3).*"
```

Comment: ty.will give it a shot and post results.

Comment: This website is extremely helpful: https://regex101.com/

Comment: the issue is what `regex` gets alongwith `egrep or grep` `$r2  -tvf  $s |  egrep -i  \/data\/data/(*tesla*|*true*) -->/system/bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected '('`  ( same thing when I escape the `/` ) If I remove the `()` bracks then it will take everything after the `|` as a new command `tar  -tvf  $s |  egrep -i /data/data/*tesla*|/data/data/*true* -->/system/bin/sh: /data/data/com.truecaller: can't execute: Is a directory
` `tar  -tvf  $s |  egrep -i "/data/data/*tesla*"|"/data/data/*true*"  <
/system/bin/sh: /data/data/*true*: not found
`

Comment: I suggest to add `.*`: `grep -i -E '/data/.*(str1|str2|str3)'`

Comment: @user1874594 try escaping the parentheses `\(...\)` as well. Also, enclose the regex expression in double quotes if you aren’t because parentheses mean something to the shell.

Comment: Also, from your comment it looks like you’ve tried the regex’s in separate double quoted strings, but that won’t work, especially with the pipe character `|` in between which means something to the shell. It needs to be all one string.

Comment: I just tried this and it worked on my MacOS: `tar tf bundle.tar | egrep -E "foo/bar/.*(Doc|Glk).*"` -- make sure you use those double quotes and keep the parens and the vertical character (pipe) inside them or the shell will interpret as something else.

Comment: that worked `Pefecto!` thanks. On a side note is it poss  ( like I mentioned in the Q to restrict your result to  a `parent directory` only e.g. `/data/data/com.ubercab` and not everything under it -  could update your A with that liner as well

Comment: In regex, you can match the beginning (^) and end ($) of a sequence. For example, ^/data/data/com\.ubercab$ will match only that sequence and no other. If you left off ^, it could have any prefix before the sequence. If you left off $, then anything could follow the sequence. Try playing with that.